# How get showduplicates rpm package using python module yum?

Tags: python, yum

I am trying to get RPM packages through the Yum API with Python. But I can not use the --showduplicates option.

```
yb = yum.YumBase()
yb.conf.showduplicates = True
yb.setCacheDir()
yb.repos.disableRepo('*')
yb.repos.enableRepo('grafana')

plist = yb.doPackageLists(patterns=sys.argv[1:])

if plist.available:
    print "Available Packages"
    for pkg in sorted(plist.available):
        print pkg, pkg.repo
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting showdups worked for me:

```
doPackageLists(pkgnarrow='all', patterns=None, showdups=True, ignore_case=False)
```

try like this:

```
plist = yb.doPackageLists(patterns=sys.argv[1:], showdups=True)
```

Relevant [Yum docs page](http://yum.baseurl.org/api/yum/yum/__init__.html#yum.__init__.YumBase.doPackageLists).